# Show success alert message after page reload

Tags: javascript, html

my target is to show the success message after the page reload. I provided a screenshot below. Thank you in advance.

https://prnt.sc/xskjsc

`HTML` and `JS`:

```js
function meronSuccess() {
  Swal.fire({
    position: 'center',
    icon: 'success',
    title: 'Registered!',
    showConfirmButton: false,
    timer: 1000
  })
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-danger text-bold float-right" id="meron" value="submit" onclick="meronSuccess()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Please also provide details on what condition you want to show the alert?

Comment: @MohitMutha I have a form submit and it's working perfectly and i just want it to show after the page reload.